# Customize the selected tab in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablayout

**Here's what I need**

[image]

**Here's what I achieved (*Ignore the size and background color*)**

[image]

My codes:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#6e00b5"/>
```

> tab_selector.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

> selected_dot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="4dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#6e00b5"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

The only problem I'm facing is to place the dot under the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simple Solution

Use `app:tabIndicator` instead of `app:tabBackground`

```
<TabLayout
    app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_dot"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="8dp">
```

**Note that** use at least double `app:tabIndicatorHeight` of tab thinkness (`4dp`) to make that fully visible.

Comment: Damn! I thought I can only change the background. I should have tried this before asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, **tab selector will work in case of tablayout**. You need to implement in your own way

You need to set **TabSlected listener** and then add below code,

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
    int position = tab.getPosition();
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);      
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.getChildAt(position);
//Below line will change selected tab textview title only.
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,null,objContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_dot))
    }
});
```

Comment: Use **tablayout** object instead of **tabstrip**.  I just edited the answer.